# React-bootstrap: Dropdown.item, onSelect returns a null target

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, react-bootstrap

I am using [react-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/react-bootstrap) and I am implementing a dropdown menu in my react web page. In my dropdown menu, I am calling a `handleClick` function when button is selected.

```html
<Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item name = "baudratestate1200" onSelect={this.handleClick}>1200</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item name = "baudratestate2400" onSelect={this.handleClick}>2400</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item name = "baudratestate4800" onSelect={this.handleClick}>4800</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item name = "baudratestate9600" onSelect={this.handleClick}>9600</Dropdown.Item>
</Dropdown.Menu>
```

Here is my `handleClick` function:

```js
handleClick = (eventkey, event) => {
  console.log(eventkey)
  console.log(event)
}
```

However, the `event.target` is null, attached below is the `console.log` from my client browser:

```
Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}
nativeEvent: (...)
type: (...)
target: null
```

I have tried binding and not-binding the function in the constructor but both have produced null values for event.target

```js
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any form of concept clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need this to get the value of the item, right?

Comment: @MoshFeu that is right, i need to get the selected value

Comment: Have you tried onSelect instead of onClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options.

1. React is throw a warning when trying to access the event

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `nativeEvent` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See ... for more information.

So, in order to get access to the original event, you should call to `event.persist()` before you access the event.

Like this:

```js
handleClick = (eventkey, event) => {
  event.persist();
  console.log(eventkey)
  console.log(event)
}
```

2. You can use the `eventkey` to pass the value

```js
change = eventkey => {
  // a.persist();
  alert(`you chosen: ${eventkey}`);
};
```

```html
<Dropdown onSelect={this.change}>
  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
    Dropdown Button
  </Dropdown.Toggle>
  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="baudratestate1200">1200</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="baudratestate2400">2400</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="baudratestate4800">4800</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="baudratestate9600">9600</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-dropdown-get-value-r7n0f

3. Call the function with hardcoded param

```js
change = option => {
  alert(`you chosen: ${option}`);
};
```

```html
<Dropdown.Item onSelect={()=> this.change("baudratestate1200")}> 1200
</Dropdown.Item>
<Dropdown.Item onSelect={()=> this.change("baudratestate2400")}> 2400
</Dropdown.Item>
<Dropdown.Item onSelect={()=> this.change("baudratestate4800")}> 4800
</Dropdown.Item>
<Dropdown.Item onSelect={()=> this.change("baudratestate9600")}> 9600
</Dropdown.Item>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-dropdown-get-value-6gknv

Comment: ahh i see, the event.persist() was the issue here, thanks so much for the help!!! passing the value through event key is a neat little trick too!

Comment: Sure :) Good luck!